# How can I efficiently maintain array in workshop?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-workshop

I have a string array in workshop that I use to store kind of temporary data in workshop.
For now what I am doing is automatically computing the array(basically push/pop operation) using typescript functions and inside workshop on event click I am storing the computed array to some other variable to make it persistent inside workshop.

But one issue I am facing sometimes set variable event is triggering even before the function based array variable is computed properly.

So is there any way to push/pop elements into array inside workshop or how can I optimize this approach?

Comment: How are you triggering the function and set variable event?

Comment: The function is triggered automatically whenever the parameter changes and set variable  event is triggered through active selection in object list.

Comment: I gave this some thought and it's surprisingly difficult to figure out given the limited affordances for array manipulation in Workshop coupled with the fact that a single variable can only be modified by one Function. I do think I have a work-around, but it's only useful in simple cases. Can you share (a) what data type is in your array, and (b) approximately how large your array needs to be?

Comment: my array has basically json stringyfied strings, array won't go beyond 50 or maybe 100 items